# How to change the "down-button" in QDateEdit with CalendarPopup?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qdateedit

I want to change the dropdown button in my `QDateEdit` but nothing works.

with:

```
QDateEdit::down-arrow{  
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    image:url('://Assets/chevron-down-dark.png');
}
```

i can change the little down-arrow-icon but if use this:

```
QDateEdit::down-button{ 
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    image:url('://Assets/chevron-down-dark.png');
 }
```

so down-button instead of down-arrow, nothing happens.
In other QSpinBoxes this works for me but not in QDateEdit.

Comment: Are you referring to the arrow used to show the calendar popup? If that's the case, you should use `::drop-down`, because that's not a spinbox arrow anymore. Otherwise, I just tested the above style sheets and they both work. Is the resource file properly compiled and imported, and the path correct? Does `QPixmap('://Assets/chevron-down-dark.png').isNull()` return `False`? What style are you using?

Comment: Perfekt.  `::drop-down` works! Thank you